# How loss_fn connected to model and optimizer in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, gradient-descent, sgd

The following code is just a template, you see the following pattern a lot in AI codes.
I have a specific question about `loss.backward()`. in the following code we have a `model`, as we pass `model.parameters()` to  `optimizer` so `optimizer` and `model` are some how connected. But there is no connection between`loss_fn` and `model` or `loss_fn` and `optimizer`. So how exactly `loss.backward()` works?

I mean, consider I add a new instance of `MSELoss` like `loss_fn_2 = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')` to the code and exactly do the same `loss_2 = loss_fn_2(y_pred, y)` and `loss_2.backward()`

**How pytorch recognize that `loss_2` is not related to `model` and only `loss` is related?**

Consider a scenario, I would like to have (`model_a` or `loss_fn_a` and `optimizer_a`) and (`model_b` or `loss_fn_b` and `optimizer_b`) so I would like to make `*_a` and `*_b` isolated from each other

```
import torch
import math


# Create Tensors to hold input and outputs.
x = torch.linspace(-math.pi, math.pi, 2000)
y = torch.sin(x)

# Prepare the input tensor (x, x^2, x^3).
p = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
xx = x.unsqueeze(-1).pow(p)

# Use the nn package to define our model and loss function.
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(3, 1),
    torch.nn.Flatten(0, 1)
)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

# Use the optim package to define an Optimizer that will update the weights of
# the model for us. Here we will use RMSprop; the optim package contains many other
# optimization algorithms. The first argument to the RMSprop constructor tells the
# optimizer which Tensors it should update.
learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
for t in range(2000):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y by passing x to the model.
    y_pred = model(xx)

    # Compute and print loss.
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    if t % 100 == 99:
        print(t, loss.item())

    # Before the backward pass, use the optimizer object to zero all of the
    # gradients for the variables it will update (which are the learnable
    # weights of the model). This is because by default, gradients are
    # accumulated in buffers( i.e, not overwritten) whenever .backward()
    # is called. Checkout docs of torch.autograd.backward for more details.
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Backward pass: compute gradient of the loss with respect to model
    # parameters
    loss.backward()

    # Calling the step function on an Optimizer makes an update to its
    # parameters
    optimizer.step()


linear_layer = model[0]
print(f'Result: y = {linear_layer.bias.item()} + {linear_layer.weight[:, 0].item()} x + {linear_layer.weight[:, 1].item()} x^2 + {linear_layer.weight[:, 2].item()} x^3')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it may seem it's not connected but loss is actually connected to the model. Let's imagine a model is a large mathematical/non linear function. (For simple explanation imagine a linear regression model which is a function in the lines of y = mx+b).

Let's imagine a model something like:

```
x1 = torch.tensor(2, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float16)
x2 = torch.tensor(3, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float16)
x3 = torch.tensor(1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float16)
x4 = torch.tensor(4, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float16)

z1 = x1 * x2
z2 = x3 * x4

f = z1 + z2

f.backward()
print(f'gradient of x1 = {x1.grad}')
# output: gradient of x1 = 3.0
# df_dx1 = x1 * 3 + 1 * 4
```

If you observe the above code, it is similar to the huge non linear function we have constructed using neural networks. Essentially loss is the output of this function, just like **f** which is the output of x1*x2 + x3*x4, so when you call loss.backward(), it means you are going back to calculating gradient of the tensors **involved** to get the loss output(torch internally handles this for you)

So whatever is involved in reaching the loss value calculation is only affected in backward which means *_a is isolated from *_b.